# circumcentre of equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, coordinate-systems

Given the circumcenter of an equilateral triangle how can i find the length of the side of the triangle?

The exact question is like this: 
An equilateral triangle with circumcenter at (-2, 5) having one side on the Y-axis, what will be the length of the side of the triangle?

I tried and tried but I could not get the traingle; instead I am getting a straight line. Can someone please explain the method to derive the answer to the above question?

Thanks

Comment: The circumcenter of any triangle is the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of the sides. On an equilateral triangle, the perpendicular bisectors are also the angle bisectors, the altitudes and the medians. You know that the distance from the point of intersection to one side is 2. What does that tell you about the length of the medians and what does the length of the medians.altitudes tell you about the length of the side?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer.

As pointed out in the comment above, the circumcenter of equilateral triangle will be same as the centroid. Also, with its $BC$ side on the $y$-axis, we have the three coordinates as under:

$A(x_1,y_1), B(0,y_2), C(0,y_3)$

With centroid at $G(-2, 5)$,

$x_G = (x_1+x_2+x_3)/3$

So $x_1$ will be $-6$.

Next I derived this from the distance formula ($AB^2 = AC^2$):

i.e. $6^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 = 6^2 + (y_3-y_1)^2$

Solving this, we get $2y_1 = y_2 + y_3\tag{1}$

Now using formula of centroid for coordinate $y$,

$(y_1 + y_2 + y_3)/3 = 5\tag{2}$

Solving $(1)$ and $(2)$:

$y_1 = 5$

According to definition of circumcenter, the distance of circumcenter from any vertex of triangle would be same. So,

$GA^2 = GB^2$

Substituting the values and simplifying, we get

$y_2^2-10y_2+13=0$

On solving,

$y_2 = 5 \pm 2\sqrt3$

Substituting value of $y_1$ in $(1)$, and solving for $y_3$, we get

For $y_2 = 5 + 2\sqrt3$ $, \;\;   y_3 = 5 - 2\sqrt3$

And for $y_2 = 5 - 2\sqrt3$ $, \;\;   y_3 = 5 + 2\sqrt3$

And now using the distance formula for vertices $B$ and $C$, the length of the side of the triangle comes to $4\sqrt3$.

While this is the correct answer, I feel this is a bit too long and there must be a simpler and more elegant way of solving it.

Thanks